gRPC make server write to client
I want to make a 'chat' between two clients using gRPC. 
The first scheme of 'communicating' between clients is:

client1 connects to server (may be sends client1_login)
client2 connects to server
client1 wants to make a chat room with client2, so it sends to server client2_login (and may be another properties, for example, client1_login)
server sends both to client1 and client2 configs for connecting to chat room

The second scheme is when 2 clients must exchange information:

client1 sends data
data must be passed to client2

How can I make this in Java with gRPC?

I'd say : yes you can.

Your question lacks detail and seeks architectural guidance rather than specific programming question. For this reason, it is likely to be closed.

gRPC is a client-server RPC. It requires that the initiator|requestor implement client functionality and the responder to implement server functionality. There's no way for a "client" to invoke RPC methods on another "client". In your 2nd scenario, the clients are peers and would need to invoke both client and server functionality in order to implement direct connections. gRPC and gRPC Java are reasonably well-documented. I encourage to follow the tutorial.
